# Distance between two points including elevation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythagorean

I am attempting to use Pythagoras to calculate the distance between two GPS points with elevation.

I.e:

> Point 1: 51.244452 -0.577235 10,000 (10,000ft above Guildford, UK)
>
> Point 2: 51.500439 -0.131811 30,000 (30,000ft above Westmister, UK)

In Python 2.7, how would you find the 'straight line' distance between these two points using Pythagoras Theorem?

Comment: "Too broad"? Really?

Comment: Distance = sqrt(Dx^2 + Dy^2 + Dz^2), where D means "delta": Dx = x1 - x2. That's simple math, not programmers' stuff.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - "too broad" seems to be the catch-all "You haven't shown any effort" close reason

Comment: Have you tried to translate the formula into Python? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Except the coordinates are on a sphere and not in R^3.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well, the OP is asking "how would you find the 'straight line' distance between these two points **using Pythagoras' Theorem**?". That's the Pythagoras' Theorem, and it doesn't concern spheres. I obviously know that the world isn't flat.

Comment: Also, the coordinates aren't in feet, unless Guildford is less than 1 foot away from Westminster

Comment: I'm aware of the Theorem itself. Perhaps the questions was poorly phrased. I am entering these values into the formula  - but this is lat long (degrees). These need to be in a Cartesian system which is where I am struggling.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: So then why not tell them that they're doing it wrong in the first place?

Comment: @Marco-Bonelli Just because the points exist in 3D space doesn't preclude them from having a straight line distance between them

Comment: @Marco, [Pythagoras did not write only one theorem](http://nrich.maths.org/5616).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that's a generalization on a spherical surface of the Pythagoras' Theorem.

Comment: I found this page here, which could help you translate the coordinates to feet.

http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why are you assuming he's wrong? You don't know what he wants to do with such information. He's asking for **straight-line** distance using such theorem, and that is the formula...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: That formula is valid for R^3. He doesn't have coordinates in R^3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to transform the coordinates to ℝ<sup>3</sup>. The formulae for doing so have been provided by [mjqxxxx](https://stackexchange.com/users/510802/mjqxxxx) in a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636993/different-ways-for-calculating-distance-between-two-geodetic-points-give-me-diff) on Math.SE:

> x = R cos θ cos ϕ
> y = R cos θ sin ϕ
> z = R sin θ

We will define the following function to handle this:

```
def sph2cart(r, theta, phi):
   return(r*math.cos(theta)*math.cos(phi), r*math.cos(theta)*math.sin(phi),
          r*math.sin(theta))
```

Assuming a spherical Earth with a radius of 20,926,000 feet:

```
>>> sph2cart(20926000+10000, 51.244452*math.pi/180, -0.577235*math.pi/180)
(13105249.663461415, -132035.2878228453, 16326392.55748538)
>>> sph2cart(20926000+30000, 51.500439*math.pi/180, -0.131811*math.pi/180)
(13045256.544829715, -30011.1344767356, 16400436.488440938)
```

And now we can shove *those* through and get the distance.